# SGS3 Android Input value of type datetime

Tags: android, jquery, input, selector

So I've been trying this for a while now, and I can't seem to figure out the problem. I have an input

```
<input type="datetime" class="nativedatetimepicker" placeholder="somestuff" name="datetime-la" id="datetime-la"/>
```

And all I want to do is set the value for it

```
$("#datetime-la").val(anytime);
```

I've tried a variety of different values for any time like new Date(), Date().toISOString(), Date().toString() etc. Nothing works. However this code works fine with iOS as well as Android 2.33 - 4.04 on all other devices.

Now if I leave it blank (which is undesireable) it can set the date and time with whatever build in function cordova has and it sets the value of the input correctly. Am I missing something here? How come this issue only comes up with the Samsung Galaxy S3 and no on other phones such as the Atrix HD.

Update:
All right I tried just making it in a simple webpage, and I believe this is an issue with the device. This is the code I tried, and it didn't work:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load(){
            document.getElementById('datetime-la').value = "something";
        }
    </script>
    <input type="datetime" class="nativedatetimepicker" name="datetime-la" id="datetime-la" style="width:50%;height:200px;"/>
    </html>
```

Comment: Since v26 Chrome for Android needs the type "datetime-local" instead of "datetime". Worked on a Galaxy S3 with Chrome 36.